# Smooth extension of a coordinate vector field

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $\varphi=(x^1,...,x^n)$ local coordinates defined on $U$. Then the coordinate vector fields
$$(\varphi^{-1})_*\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$$
determines smooth vector fields on $U$. Can these always be smoothly extended to $M$? (It may vanish outside $U$.) I think they should, in order to make other definitions like the connection and curvature tensor valid. I consider the books of John M. Lee.

I know that a general smooth vector field on an open set of $M$ cannot always be smoothly extended, take for example: $X:(0,1)\to T\mathbb R, x\to \frac 1{x(x-1)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}$.

Comment: Well, you can make them vanish smoothly, and then they are extended to the whole $M$.
If you want to extend them smoothly without make them vanish, then it's not always possible. Think of $M=S^2$.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz, how can you make them vanish smoothly? Via partition of unity? Do you maybe have a reference?

Comment: I have tried to ask the same thing [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404220/extending-local-smooth-function-f-u-subset-m-rightarrow-mathbbr). The answer is that you can't always extend a function defined on an open subset to a larger set. The best i can do is to extend the restriction of the function to some closed subset inside the original domain.